# SQL Data Conversion Failed DateTime

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime

I have a update query as follows

`UPDATE EcommerceCustomerActiveSites 
  SET SubscriptionExpDate = '19/08/2021 12:15:17 PM', IsEnabled = 1 
  WHERE ContactCode = 'CCTC-002833'`

This gives me an error as follows

`The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.`

However. when I do a select query from the same table and copy a sample value from the `SubscriptionExpDate` column, it returns the same format as my insert statement!

```
19/08/2021 12:27:06 PM  -- Value From Select
19/08/2021 12:15:17 PM  -- Value From Insert
```

Does anyone have any clues?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a more appropriate value for the constant string:

```
UPDATE EcommerceCustomerActiveSites 
  SET SubscriptionExpDate = '2012-08-19 12:15:17',
      IsEnabled = 1 
  WHERE ContactCode = 'CCTC-002833';
```

The format for `datetime` constants is described in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx).